# C# - Merge Unmanaged Code DLL's into .exe without storing to Disk

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exe

Is it possible to merge an unmanaged .dll into a .exe without having to temporarily storing it as a file?

I have System.Data.SQLite.Core installed and it has a managed .dll `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and an unmanaged .dll `SQLite.Interop.dll`.

I was able to merge `System.Data.SQLite.dll` with no trouble at all using Resources.

But it doesn't work with SQLite.Interop.dll, I can have it as an embedded resource, but as soon as I hook it with AssemblyResolve, my application instantly closes.

Perhaps theres a way to store it as a file without seeing the file next to the .exe anywhere, then Assembly.LoadFrom on it, then remove that already hidden file and it would still work? That would end up as essentially the same thing as AssemblyResolve for Managed dll's but without having to write and then read, managed you can just read from the resources.

File-size is NOT an issue here for my app.
So any ideas you guys got, im happy to receive.
If you need more information from me, im happy to give.

Side-note: The .dll isnt required to be referenced. I dont use it anywhere, it just gets outputed with .targets into the build directory.

Comment: From my knowledge, unmanaged DLL's must be loaded from disk. There is no `LoadLibrary` Windows API function to load an unmanaged DLL from working memory. The `AssemblyResolve` event is not fired on a missing unmanaged DLL. And of course the SQLite.Interop.dll is used, not directly by your code, but by the managed assembly. So, keep it in the target directory. See: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: @KBO Thank you, I didn't know about that :) Would I still be able to load the sqlite.interop.dll from disk atleast? as im trying my best to make my application a 1-file-only app.

Comment: You're welcome;-) You don't have to load it manually. It is loaded automatically be the System.Data.SQLite.dll, if required. There are many PInvoke calls using `DllImport` in System.Data.SQLite.dll. I guess, the 1-file-only app goal will not work as expected.

Comment: @KBO Yeah my dreams are RIP. I went ahead and just un-done all the other 9 .dll's I embedded, and just went ahead back to a dependency filled folder lmao